# Envoy crashes on Raspberry PI 4 when tcmalloc tries to allocate memory

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, envoyproxy

I am trying to run [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io) on RP4 and 64bit Raspberry Pi OS.

Envoy 1.20 crashes with:

```
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/system-alloc.cc:550] MmapAligned() failed (size, alignment) 1073741824 1073741824 @ 0x559342edc4 0x55934211a4 0x5593420be4 0x559340a4c0
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/arena.cc:34] FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data (bytes, object-size) 131072 48 @ 0x559342f0d4 0x559340a534
```

Envoy 1.23 crashes with

```
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/system-alloc.cc:631] MmapAligned() failed - unable to allocate with tag (hint, size, alignment) - is something limiting address placement? 0x151880000000 1073741824 1073741824 @ 0x55941cfa88 0x55941cb6a0 0x55941caf48 0x55941b2f4c 0x55941c8010 0x55941c7e2c 0x55941a78a8 0x55940e6c00 0x55940e2298 0x559406f484 0x559419dbd0 0x7f834774ac
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/arena.cc:58] FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data (bytes, object-size); is something preventing mmap from succeeding (sandbox, VSS limitations)? 131072 600 @ 0x55941cfde4 0x55941b2fdc 0x55941c8010 0x55941c7e2c 0x55941a78a8 0x55940e6c00 0x55940e2298 0x559406f484 0x559419dbd0 0x7f834774ac
```

Tested also on envoy `1.17`, `1.18`, `1.19`, and `1.22` (it seems that arm64 is supported only starting from `1.17`). Same behaviour.

### How to reproduce:

In Docker:

```bash
docker run --rm envoyproxy/envoy:v1.24-latest
```

On a host machine:

```bash
envoy_location=$(podman run --rm --entrypoint which docker.io/envoyproxy/envoy:v1.23-latest envoy)
container_id=$(podman create which docker.io/envoyproxy/envoy:v1.23-latest)
podman cp "${container_id}":"${envoy_location}" ./envoy
podman rm -v "${container_id}"
./envoy
```

If you are using Docker then replace `podman` with `docker` (also you may use `envoyproxy/envoy` as a repository name).

I am using RP4 8GB.

Comment: The same occurs with v1.24.0.
`envoy@dc2470c4f934:/$ /usr/local/bin/envoy 
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/system-alloc.cc:614] MmapAligned() failed - unable to allocate with tag (hint, size, alignment) - is something limiting address placement? 0x46a180000000 1073741824 1073741824 @ 0x556b2908fc ...
external/com_github_google_tcmalloc/tcmalloc/arena.cc:58] FATAL ERROR: Out of memory trying to allocate internal tcmalloc data (bytes, object-size); is something preventing mmap from succeeding (sandbox, VSS limitations)? 131072 600 @ 0x556b290c5c`

Comment: Have you found a solution for that problem already?

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was the kernel options on the raspberry pi os are incompatible with envoy. Some possible solutions are to compile a new envoy binary disabling tcmalloc or use a prebuilt container ([referenced in the original answer](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/23339#issuecomment-1290509732) for example "thegrandpkizzle/envoy:1.24.0")